# Creating Index on Max Decode function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, database-indexes, functional-index

We have a table which stores user information in attribute name and value pairs. On this table, we have created a view by transposing the rows to columns using decode. `MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'FirstName',attribute_Value)) FirstName`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW vw_get_userinfo
("USER_ID", "FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "USEREMAIL",
  "STREET", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIPCODE", "COUNTRY")
AS
  SELECT
    t.user_id,
    t.firstname,
    t.lastname,
    t.useremail,
    t.street,
    t.city,
    t.state,
    t.country
  FROM (WITH
          tempattributes AS (SELECT
                               user_id,
                               attribute_name,
                               attribute_value
                             FROM user_details)
        SELECT
          user_id,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'FirstName', attribute_value)) FirstName,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'LastName', attribute_value))  LastName,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'UserEmail', attribute_value)) UserEmail,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'Street', attribute_value))    Street,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'City', attribute_value))      City,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'State', attribute_value))     State,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'ZipCode', attribute_value))   Zipcode,
          MAX(DECODE(attribute_name, 'Country', attribute_value))   Country
        FROM tempattributes
        GROUP BY user_id
       ) t
```

During explain plan, a full scan is performed when querying with the first name field. The function-based index is not applicable in this case as Index won't work on the group by function. Is there any way I can create the index on the `FirstName` attribute?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want performance suggestions, you should show the entire query.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I have included the query.

Comment: I don't see any filter predicate in the query. You are projecting all the rows from the table. Obviously a `full table scan` is required. When you are filtering the data based on a `column` then it makes sense to create an `index` on that column. If you are filtering the data based on an `expression`, then you need to create `function-based index` on that column. You don't need an index for projecting the rows. Post the **EXPLAIN PLAN**. See [How to create and display EXPLAIN PLAN](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/31/oracle-explain-plan/)

Comment: Thanks @LalitKumarB. When I check explain plan for the below query, it shows range scan as an index has been created for user_id field on user_details table. SELECT * FROM VW_GET_USERINFO WHERE USER_ID='XYZ'. But when we use FIRST_NAME as filter, it results in full scan as there is no index created.

Comment: @RealChembil Again, you create an index on a static table column or an expression which includes a static table column.

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there any way I can create the index on the FirstName attribute?"

No.  Indexes are built on table columns.  The table underlying your view has a generic structure of (key, value) pairs.  This approach seems flexible and time-saving for application developers but the price is paid by the user in poor performance.

And of course you still end up defining a fixed set of attributes, only the structure is expressed in a view rather than a table.  So what flexibility have you gained really?

If you don't want to define a fixed set of attributes, for whatever reason, you should choose a supported approach such as XML, or JSON in 12c.  At least their attributes are indexable.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This may not help performance, but you can just write the query as:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'FirstName',attribute_Value)) as FirstName,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'LastName',attribute_Value)) as LastName,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'UserEmail',attribute_Value)) as UserEmail,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'Street',attribute_Value)) as Street,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'City',attribute_Value)) as City,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'State',attribute_Value)) as State,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'ZipCode',attribute_Value)) as ZipCode,
       MAX(DECODE(attribute_name,'Country',attribute_Value)) as Country
FROM user_details
GROUP BY user_id;
```

(Note:  I much prefer `CASE` to `DECODE()`, but I'm leaving your original logic in.)

Oracle has a good optimizer, but it is possible that the nested `with` affected it, so this might perform better.  You can also try an index on `user_details(user_id, attribute_name, attribute_value)` to see if that improves performance.